# Adding a task with in a task in a gruntfile

Tags: gruntjs

I have gruntfile as below:

```
       concat: {
        options: {
            banner: '<%= banner %>',
            stripBanners: true
        },
        one: {
            src: ['src/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_ac.js'
        },

        two: {
            src: ['/types/**/*.js'],
            dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_lib.js'
        },

        all: {
        }
    },.....  and so on
```

Now if i register the task like:
       grunt.registerTask('basic', ['concat:all']);

I want both one and two to run. How shall i add this option in

```
     all: {
          // what i need to add here to include one and two both?
     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to add another target if you're registering a task to point to two targets. Just do:

```
grunt.registerTask('basic', ['concat:one', 'concat:two']);
```

Otherwise if you're intending on concatenating the files from one and two all together do:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    one: {
      src: ['src/**/*.js'],
      dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_ac.js'
    },
    two: {
      src: ['/types/**/*.js'],
      dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_lib.js'
    },
    all: {
      src: ['<%= concat.one.src %>', '<%= concat.two.src %>'],
      dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_all.js'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I like this one's flexibility better

Answer (score 2):

Grunt allow  you to define the main target. So in your default target define as

```
grunt.registerTask( 'basic',['concat']);
```

This will activate the concat:one and concat:two.

If you need to activate a specific target, define your register task as follows.

```
    grunt.registerTask( 'basic',['concat:one']);
```

If you need to run the specific task which has multiple targets then you can define as follows.

```
all: {
     tasks: ['one','two']
    }
```

Then in your registerTask call the all target.

```
 grunt.registerTask( 'basic',['concat:all']);
```

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'gruntfile' plugin where you are provided with more powerful functionality and you can add tasks of one grunt file to another using concat.

Refer the link : https://github.com/shama/gruntfile